# Javascript: traversing only HTML DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags, traversal

I need to traverse the DOM of a HTML page without taking in nodes, like textnodes, that are not elements. I want just the elements that are tags in the HTML page. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Your phrasing is very confusing. Are you saying that you only want to fetch elements that did not exist when the page was originally loaded? If so, when exactly do you need to fetch them?

Comment: *"...only HTML DOM elements explicitly written as HTML tags"* That's what an element is. If you created it with tags *(or a single tag for void ones)*, it's an element.

Comment: @user2736012 when using childNodes function I get other stuff (if I am not wrong), I just want the tags.

Comment: Just trying to get definitions straight. Everything in the DOM is a node. When it becomes a DOM, there really aren't any tags any more. Tags are what you write in your HTML markup. So if you want nodes that were created from the tags in your markup, that means you want *elements*. To filter out non-element nodes (like text nodes and comment nodes), you use the `.nodeType` property. Element nodes have a `.nodeType` of `1`.

Comment: ...and FYI, you can use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` to get only the elements *(though IE8 and lower will include comment nodes if any exist)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing how you are actually navigating the tree, I can just give you a basic example showing how to check the [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType)

```
function getFirstChildElement (el) {
    el = el.firstChild;
    while (el && el.nodeType !== 1)
        el = el.nextSibling;
    return el;
}
```

Comment: @epascarello what dose el.nodeType !== 1 exactly mean?

Comment: @P5music epascarello gave you a link. Click on it and you'll see all node types. `1` is for `ELEMENT_NODE`.

Comment: @dystroy Doesn't !== mean "not equal"? Shouldn't be == instead?

Comment: @P5music Depends on the goal. Here the code is correct when the goal is to find the first node which is an element (and thus skip the other ones).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `children` property of the parent element instead of using `childNodes`, `firstChild`, `lastChild`, and the like...

The `children`, unlike `childNodes` refers to only the **elements** (the tags) and skips other nodes like **text** which is exactly what you want.

Just to illustrate, here's a short demo:

```
function showChildElements (el) {
    for (var i = 0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
        alert(el.children[i].tagName);
    }
}
```